# How do I get the value of my plugin wordpress option?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I have a css value that is stored in my plugin for custom css

How do I retrieve the option?

```
//1  added the section

add_settings_section(
    'custom_css_textarea',
    'Enter Custom Styles here.',
    'simpledir_callback_custom_css_textarea',
    'simpledir'
);

//2 added the feild

add_settings_field(
        'custom_css_textarea',
        'Custom Css textarea',
        'simpledir_callback_custom_css_textarea',
        'simpledir',
        'simpledir_custom_section_admin',
        [ 'id' => 'custom_css_textarea', 'label' => 'Remove new post and comment links from the Toolbar' ]
    );

//3 made a callback function
```

How do I access this textarea value? It is easily updated and saves but I don't know how to retrieve it outside of my callback function

```
$css = get_option( 'custom-css-textarea' );
```

Answer (score 1):

You have name_section and id_field with the same value.
This worked for me

```
add_settings_section(
   'name_section',
   __( 'Title of Page', 'textdomain' ),
   'callback_render',
   'page_for_show_section');

add_settings_field( 
    'id_field', 
    __( 'Label', 'textdomain' ), 
    'callback_for_render_option'),
    'page_for_show_section',
    'name_section', 
    // The array of arguments to pass to the callback. In this case, just a description.
    array(                              
            'Activate this setting to display the header.'
        )
    );
```